# How to convert char array to string

Tags: c++

```
char n[12];
sgx_read_rand(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&n),
                sizeof(n));
mbedtls_printf("ENCLAVE: Salt for the password: %llu\n", *(char *)n);
string salt(n);
mbedtls_printf("ENCLAVE: Salt for the password: %s\n", salt.c_str());
```

It gives output as:

ENCLAVE: Salt for the password: 4294967209

ENCLAVE: Salt for the password: ���Æ��Ѩ�

How to covert it into string?Is it even possible?

Function signature:

```
/* sgx_read_rand()
 * Parameters:
 *      rand - the buffer to receive the random number
 *      length_in_bytes - the number of bytes to read the random number
 * Return Value:
 *      SGX_SUCCESS - success
 *      SGX_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER - the parameter is invalid
 *      SGX_ERROR_UNEXPECTED - HW failure of RDRAND instruction
*/
sgx_status_t SGXAPI sgx_read_rand(unsigned char *rand, size_t length_in_bytes);
```

What I wanted:

I wanted the salt to get as a string data type. My Password is a string data type and I want to concatenate salt with it. As you can see when I try to get string from char array, I get binary data but when I use %llu for char array I get readable data. I want the same readable data in string.

Update from Linux SGX developers document:
sgx_read_rand

```
The sgx_read_rand function is used to generate a random number inside
the enclave.
Syntax
sgx_status_t sgx_read_rand(
unsigned char *rand,
size_t length_in_bytes
);

rand variable:
A pointer to the buffer that receives the random number. The pointer cannot be NULL. The rand buffer can be either within or outside the enclave, but it is not allowed to be across the enclave boundary or wrapped around.
length_in_bytes [in]
The length of the buffer (in bytes)
```

Link to the developer reference: https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel_sgx_sdk_developer_reference_for_linux_os_pdf.pdf

Everyone who downvoted the question, Have a look here:
https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/issues/263

so I did this based on comments:

```
char n[12];
sgx_read_rand(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&n),
                sizeof(n));

for(int i=0;i<12;++i)
{
    mbedtls_printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)n[i]);
}
```

And the output is

```
15
73
8
4294967229
84
4294967176
53
4294967198
4294967268
91
4294967275
4294967224
```

I think this function just generates random bytes. Any opinion?

Comment: This is random binary data, what are you expecting?

Comment: I want to convert into string data type as I want to concatenate the salt to the password which is a string data type.

Comment: `string salt(n, 12);` will convert to string. You will see similar output as you saw before.  I am getting the sense that you were not happy with the output you got in the first place , can you elaborate on exactly what you want and perhaps provide examples?

Comment: It looks like you did. The contents of `n` is random data, but your first `printf()` isn't printing the _data_, it's printing the _address_ of that data while your second `printf()` is printing the _data_. That's why the outputs differ.

Comment: Also, that specialized `printf` you're using -- you do see they use different format specfiers, right?  So why are you using the value of the output to determine if it was translated to a string properly?  One output is formatted one way, the second another way.

Comment: How could I get the value 4294967209 as a string?

Comment: @M.M: I tried string salt(n, 12); but it still outputs binary data.

Comment: @tdk001 actually the first printf is undefined behaviour (passing a `char` argument to `%llu`)

Comment: @RoshanMehta -- M.M beat me to it.  It is undefined behavior to try and fool `printf` into printing something that doesn't match the format specifier.  The `n` is a character array, thus it is only compatible with `"%s"` or similar format specifier.  You have binary data -- why are you trying to make numerical sense of it?  It is what it is.

Comment: @RoshanMehta you do not want `4294967209` as a string. That value only represents the first byte of the binary data.

Comment: I just wonder why the developer document says it generates the random number.

Comment: By the way everyone who downvoted the question, Have a look here:https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/issues/263

Comment: @RoshanMehta -- Instead of showing us faulty `printf` output, how about telling us *exactly* what each character is that is returned?  You do that by inspecting the memory or character array, preferably with a debugger or just print each character value in a simple loop.  Then maybe it will make more sense to us (and maybe to you also).

Comment: @RoshanMehta `for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) { printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)n[i]); }` -- Something similar to that is more illustrative of the string data that's returned.  Your question shows us an integer, and then in the second print statement, a bunch of unknown characters -- neither is of any help.  Print the actual values of the characters, then determine what would be considered the "string output" you want to see.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I just wanted the random salt in string data type for my password which I could concatenate.

Comment: I got it PaulMcKenzie. The function generates uint_8t data types per byte.

Comment: Now that you actually printed out the values (the huge numbers in your output are more than likely supposed to be negative), how are you going to stringify that data?  What are your expectations as to what the string should look like?  Also note that character `8` is a control character (backspace).  How were you going to represent that value in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes it's possible to convert it to a string. But you have to understand the types you're using.

```
char n[12];
```

Here n is of type char*. If you want to convert a char* to a string it has to be null terminated. So after you fill the array with random numbers, you have to:

```
n[sizeof(n)-1] = '\0';
```

then

```
string salt(n);
```

contains a the string representing your char array. But be warned, the random numbers might already contain a '\0', so the length of the resulting string might vary. ( 0 to 11 characters)

Let me explain, what happend in your code:

```
mbedtls_printf("ENCLAVE: Salt for the password: %llu\n", *(char *)n);
```

Here, because n already is a char*, you take *n, which is the same as n[0], and output it as %llu (unsigned long long int). The output 4294967209 in hex is 0xFFFFFFA9. You get this value because you converted the char n[0] = 0xA9 = -87 to unsigned long long int.

The string you're getting later "���Æ��Ѩ�" is correct, that are the random characters you've created. But it was pure luck, that there was a '\0' in your memory, which terminated the string. Also this looks like Unicode, I'm not sure what your environment is, but you might need to convert to wchar_t depending in which format your password is stored. But that's beyond the scope of your question.